# prove that the interior of the difference between a set and its interior is empty

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and let int(A) denote the interior of A. Prove that int(A\int(A))=$\emptyset$.

my method was to suppose that $int(A \setminus int(A)) \neq \emptyset$ then there exists a vector $\vec{x}$ belonging to $int(A \setminus int(A))$. dont know what to do next.

Comment: $\text{int}(A-\text{int}(A)) \subseteq \text{int}(\overline{A}-\text{int}(A)) = \text{int}(\partial A) = \emptyset$

Answer (score 3):

If $\text{int}(A \setminus \text{int}(A)) \ne \varnothing$, then $A \setminus \text{int}(A)$ contains an open ball, call it $B$. Then $B \cup \text{int}(A)$ is an open subset of $A$ that is strictly larger than $\text{int}(A)$, which contradicts the fact that $\text{int}(A)$ is the largest open set contained in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $int(A\setminus int(A))\neq\emptyset$, then consider $x\in int(A\setminus int(A))\subset A\setminus int(A)$. You get $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta(x)\subset A\setminus int(A)\subset A$ where $B_\delta(x)$ is the $\delta$-ball around $x$. But then $x\in int(A)$ which contradicts $x\in A\setminus int(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$int(A \setminus int(A))= int(A \cap int(A)^c) =int(A)\cap int(int(A)^c)\subseteq int(A) \cap int(A)^c=\emptyset$$

Comment: I think it should be $int(A\cap int(A)^c)=int(A)\cap int(int(A)^c)\subset int(A)\cap int(A)^c$.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt You're right. I have corrected it.

Comment: if a set is a subset of the empty set, does this imply that the set is also empty?

Comment: @BamfordWang Yes, of course.